# Run Asterisk AGI when the call is initialized

Tags: asterisk

Is there any way to run an AGI when the call is initialized? Something like below.

`exten => AGI(script)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
 [inbound_context]
 exten => _X.,1,AGI(script)
```